# mongodb sort by multi field operation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In mongodb I can sort the find outout with

```
db.orders.find().sort({ amount: -1 })
```

If in my db I have the fields amount and prices.
How could I sort by a operation over two fields of the db? similar to

```
db.orders.find().sort( { prices*amount/2: -1 } )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [`aggregate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) and with [`$multiply`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/) operator, something like this:

```
db.companies.aggregate([
{$project: { _id:0, name:1, prices:1, amount:1, 
             total: {$multiply: [ "$prices", "$amount", 0.5 ]}}},
{ $sort: {total: -1}} 
]);
```

Edit: If you want to add a number:

```
db.companies.aggregate([
{$project: { _id:0, name:1, prices:1, amount:1, 
            mult: {$multiply: [ "$prices", "$amount", 0.5 ]} }},
{ $project:  { prices:1, amount:1, total: { $add: [ "$mult", 1 ] } } },
{ $sort: {total: -1}} 
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, what about of a operation like ` prices/amount*0.5 + 1` ?

Comment: You can add another stage to add the number 1. Let me edit my post.